# Is it illegal to deny or charge customers for receipts?

Tags: unprofessional-behavior, australia, law, invoices, customer-relation

I've had an unfortunate experience with a passive aggressive secretary who initially demanded payment when I presented her with a request for a digital record of my invoice/receipt history. I promptly gave in to save time; I agreed to pay the fee, at which stage she flat out refused to provide me with the information. I don't require a printout or postage or anything that will incur costs beyond a the time it takes to send an email and it seems to me a reasonable request. They have my payment details on file, so charges are processed automatically with no invoices or receipts sent out.

I don't want to give too much personally identifiable information such as location, etc. But surely there are laws against this kind of conduct. I'm not quite sure how to deal with the matter. She is effectively a barrier between myself and anyone else within the company, which makes it difficult to go above or around her. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Wait?  You paid a fee for a receipt but then still were not given a receipt?

Comment: There are laws for this. Problem is, they just depend on the location...

Comment: @Donald it's unclear if i've been charged or not. it's too early to tell. I assume I haven't been charged, since my request was ultimately denied. I think it's beside the point although I do suspect I've been routinely overcharged, which is perhaps why she is hesitant to provide evidence of it.

Comment: @MatthewGaiser I suspected this might be the case.I am in Western Australia, and this is the secretary of a medical professional. I've shown considerable restraint in my dealings with her, but I'm about to lose my patience.

Comment: This isn't a work place problem or question. You should contact your local government consumer affairs office.

Comment: A transaction receipt is NOT the same thing as a "digital record of my invoice/receipt history".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a workplace question, but instead a complaint against a company as a member of public requesting an invoice history

Comment: Does that Medical professional have some kind of medical license? If so, you may want to contact their licensing board. Also, do you have proof that the secretary denied you that invoicing history? Or that she tried charging you for it? It's one thing to find out if something is illegal. It's another thing to prove that the incident happened the exact way you described.

Comment: Were you given a receipt at the time of the charges?  If you are asking for replacement copies, you are asking for extra work.

Comment: @cdkMoose I think it's irrelevant, but no. My card is just charged automatically on a monthly and annual basis.

Comment: @Draken You're wrong. Sorry fella.

Comment: @voices feel free to update your question with the relevant details, in its current state, that is how it reads

Answer (score 8):

**It is illegal in your jurisdiction of Western Australia**

> A consumer who wants to make a claim about faulty goods or services against a supplier or manufacturer will usually need to show they obtained the goods or services from the supplier or manufacturer. The same applies to gift recipients.
>
> Businesses are understandably concerned to ensure claims made to them about goods and services are genuine.
>
> The best 'proof of purchase' is a tax invoice or receipt. Businesses have an obligation to provide proof of purchase to consumers for goods or services valued at $75 or more (excluding GST). Where a transaction is valued at less than $75, consumers have the option of requiring a proof of purchase to be provided within seven days of the transaction.

One method of resolution (albeit extreme) would be to contact Consumer Protection of the Government of Western Australia.

https://www.commerce.wa.gov.au/consumer-protection/receipts-and-proof-purchases

I cannot find anything in Western Australian law about it, but I did find federal rules that require an invoice to be provided free of charge:

https://www.accc.gov.au/consumers/prices-surcharges-receipts/receipts-proof-of-purchase

Comment: Thanks, but is it legal (or reasonable) to charge for a digital invoice or receipt?

Comment: @voices see edit

Comment: The OP makes it sound like they are asking for an account history, not for an invoice or receipt at point of purchase.